# Upper case Usage for text elements

Tags: javascript, css

I have an anchor tag with on load function

```
onload="<%VectorAsset("Please enter HERE", 400,40)%>"
```

The word `HERE` is hard coded. I want to remove the hard coded uppercase and want **CSS** or **Java Script** do it. I tried applying `{text-transform: uppercase }` property but the whole sentence is being capitalized. I need only the particular word `HERE` to be capitalized. How can i do it?

Comment: The question is not clear. You should provide more about the code, and more clear code (What is VectorAsset? How can we know what does it do?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for whatever reason you really want to do it with pure CSS, you can instead append the text on with the `:after` pseudo-selector and call the CSS property `text-transform: uppercase` on it.

```
<span id="asdf">asdf</span>

#asdf:after {
  content: "hjkl";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g5nzakhw/

---

Otherwise (and I believe this makes more sense), give the CSS something to select by wrapping the desired text in an inline element and just call `text-transform: uppercase` on that.

```
<h3 id="asdf">asdf<span>hjkl</span></h3>

#asdf span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g5nzakhw/1/

Comment: No prob :) you should accept it as the answer if it solved your problem though

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate those two groups, so you can make individual operations on them.

```
<span>Please enter <span>HERE</span></span>

<span>Please enter <span class="AllUpperCase" id="UpperCaseMe">HERE</span></span>

<span>Please enter <span><%VectorAsset("HERE", 400,40)%></span></span>

<script>
    // onload
    var $UpperCase = $("#UpperCaseMe");
    $UpperCase.html($UpperCase.html().toUpperCase());
</script>
```